# Serve all font files with an additional header in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, http-headers

I'd like to add the following HTTP header to all responses stemming from a request for a font-file in Spring MVC:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

So, I know how to set up a simple static request mapping...

`<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />`

But how can I add the necessary header? I know that I could implement a controller that responds to all `/fonts/` requests and adds the header, but that seems like major overkill. Is there something simpler/more lightweight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to implement a special controller for this. You can use an interceptor which extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.

The postHandle method is passed the `HttpServletResponse`. You can set the header there. This interceptor can be configured to apply to requests to a specific path.

See the Spring docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).